# Cannot save Bitmapsource to Bitmapimage

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to save an image from a users Clipboard. I am able to get all the correct data from the clipboard image into the Bitmapsource. I am trying to save to a Bitmapimage so I can upload a file to a website. When converting the Bitmapsource to a Bitmapimage, all of the Bitmapimages data stays null and will throw an exception.

```
        private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control) && (e.Key == Key.V))
        {
            if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
            {
                BitmapSource bitmapSource = Clipboard.GetImage();

                JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                BitmapImage bImg = new BitmapImage();

                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
                encoder.Save(memoryStream);

                bImg.BeginInit();
                bImg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray());
                bImg.EndInit();

                var client = new WebClient();
                var uri = bImg.UriSource;
                var path = uri.AbsolutePath;
                //client.UploadFile(link, path);
            }
        }
    }
```

Both

```
var uri = bImg.UriSource;
var path = uri.AbsolutePath;
```

Will throw an unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WpfApplication1.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a BitmapImage from its `StreamSource` property will not magically set its `UriSource` property. You do not need that BitmapImage at all.

Write the original BitmapSource to a FileStream instead of a MemoryStream, and upload that file:

```
string path = ...

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    encoder.Save(fileStream);
}

client.UploadFile(link, path);
```

---

It may even be unnecessary to create an intermediate file. Just upload the buffer of the MemoryStream:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    encoder.Save(memoryStream);
    client.UploadData(link, memoryStream.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Saving a temp to the filestream was the solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The other one should work too, and saves you a temporary file.